# Criar uma Tabela-Relacionamento(N:N) que relaciona a uma Tabela-Normal e uma outra Tabela-Relacionamento(N:N) no SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, table, relacionamento, sql-server-2014, entidade-relacionamento

Estou tentando criar esse Script de Bando de Dados SQL Server, mas quando executo acontece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 161 Não existem chaves primárias ou
>   candidatas na tabela de referência 'tblFornecedorInsumo' que
>   correspondam à lista de colunas de referência na chave estrangeira
>   'FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblFornecedorInsumo'.

---

> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 161 Não foi possível criar a
>   restrição ou o índice. Consulte os erros anteriores.

OBS: "FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblFornecedorInsumo" é o nome do relacionamento da tblInsumosDaComposicao.

Esse erros acontecem por causa do tipo de relacionamento na tabela tblInsumosDaComposicao que estou tentando Criar. Ela é uma tabela N:N que tenta criar relacionamento com uma tabela normal(tblComposicao) e uma tabela relacionamento N:N(tblFornecedorInsume -> que é o relacionamento da tblInsumo e a tblFornecedor onde seus atributos PK são também FK (IDInsumo e IDFornecedor)).

Abaixo o código que estou tentando executar para criação dessas tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE tblInsumo
(
    IDInsumo INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Descricao VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Deletado BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_tblInsumo PRIMARY KEY (IDInsumo),
);
GO


CREATE TABLE tblFornecedor
(
    IDFornecedor INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    NomeFantasia VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    RazaoSocial VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    FisicaJuridica BIT NOT NULL,
    CpfCnpj VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    Deletado BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_tblFornecedor PRIMARY KEY (IDFornecedor)
);
GO


CREATE TABLE tblComposicao
(
    IDComposicao INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Descricao VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    Total DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    Deletado BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_tblComposicao PRIMARY KEY (IDComposicao),
);
GO


CREATE TABLE tblFornecedorInsumo
(
    IDInsumo INT NOT NULL,
    IDFornecedor INT NOT NULL,
    PrecoCusto DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    MargemLucro DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    PrecoVenda DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    DataAtualizacao DATE NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_tblForneceInsumo PRIMARY KEY (IDFornecedor, IDInsumo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblForneceInsumo_tblInsumo FOREIGN KEY(IDInsumo) REFERENCES tblInsumo(IDInsumo),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblForneceInsumo_tblFornecedor FOREIGN KEY(IDFornecedor) REFERENCES tblFornecedor(IDFornecedor)
);
GO

     ------Tabela que não é criada e gera as mensagens de erro------
CREATE TABLE tblInsumosDaComposicao
(
    IDComposicao INT NOT NULL,
    IDInsumo INT NOT NULL,
    IDFornecedor INT NOT NULL,
    Quantidade DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    Total DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
    Deletado BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_tblInsumosDaComposicao PRIMARY KEY (IDComposicao, IDInsumo, IDFornecedor),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblComposicao FOREIGN KEY(IDComposicao) REFERENCES tblComposicao(IDComposicao),
    CONSTRAINT FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblFornecedorInsumo FOREIGN KEY(IDInsumo, IDFornecedor) REFERENCES tblFornecedorInsumo(IDInsumo, IDFornecedor)
);
GO
```

Agradeço desde já a Ajuda !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na declaração da restrição `FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblFornecedorInsumo` é necessário que as colunas sejam declaradas na mesma ordem.

Onde está

```
CONSTRAINT FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblFornecedorInsumo 
           FOREIGN KEY(IDInsumo, IDFornecedor) 
           REFERENCES tblFornecedorInsumo(IDInsumo, IDFornecedor)
```

substitua por

```
CONSTRAINT FK_tblInsumosDaComposicao_tblFornecedorInsumo 
           FOREIGN KEY (IDFornecedor, IDInsumo) 
           REFERENCES tblFornecedorInsumo (IDFornecedor, IDInsumo)
```